# default file locations per platform?

Tags: qt, cross-platform, conventions, application-settings

I'm making a (qt) cross platform application that stores both cache and settings files. After a lot of searching, i still haven't found how and where to store them. *Please note that i want to use QT's stuff only where i would otherwise reinvent the wheel or save insane amounts of time; i want absolute control over the behavior of the application and qt is rather random or inefficient at times.*

For linux, the default would be /etc//, but there's no write access there and my app writes changes to it's config file. for cache, that would be /var//, but by default there is no write access either. the settings and cache should preferably be user independent as it's server software.

I have thought of several solutions, but they don't seem very elegant:

- Let the installer create those directories with the right permissions (that means i'm going to need an installer... bleh)
- store it all in the user's home directory, losing user independence
- Let QT handle it (i really don't like this one)

any ideas? what's best practice? where does this stuff go on windows and mac?

**Some clarification:**
It's a server application that is supposed to run independently of a single user, so it's not desired to store anything at all in /home. It's also not using any gui features of QT, the server is going to be managed by either settings files or a separate GUI that communicates with the server over IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use these folders your application should be executed partially or completely with root privileges.

Another thing you can do is:

- setup a work directory `myDir` for your application, and everything is stored inside this work directory (the same way qtcreator does if you want an example).
- Save your directory in a non-user specific location. I think `/opt` [is a good candidate](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html).
- In `myDir` the required privilege to access\modify\execute files you want are set up for the users group.
- `myDir` itself requires root to delete, but not the files inside.
- Make the settings for your Qt application kinda self contained using [QSettings](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsettings.html)

Without an installer *you will be the installer*: moving around executing scripts and commands, and eventually writing an installation document (we are doing this in our startup now and it is just painful, we are in the process of changing to full installer mode)

Note : Not an expert, but using two types of machines as servers seems like you guys are really looking for trouble. Or your app is targeting servers of all types maybe?

Comment: The application is intended to be sold in the future if it proves to work as designed during internal use. Basically it's a file/folder synchronization program that synchronizes files between the server and the clients. That is why it has to be cross platform, so users can run it on old surplus hardware without having to install a specific OS first.

Comment: Ok make sense. How are your clients going to install it? you can write an install script now, because you are probably going to need this auto-install functionality anyway...

Comment: I actually want to set default directories per platform with #ifdef's, and distribute a single binary (or archive, since you need a licence to static link QT) that when you run it automatically "installs" itself. A bit like utorrent does it.

Comment: No application should "executed partially or completely with root privileges". That's just no option for UI/user applications at all in any sane environment.

Answer (score 0):

User applications don't store user-writable data such as configuration files or caches in /etc or /var, they usually use and should use $HOME/.appname, or, nowadays often used, $HOME/.config/appname (config) and $HOME/.local/ (for data). Qt should do a good job here for the config data if you use QSettings and set the Application name etc. /etc is for daemons, system configuration and the like, not for user applications. There might be readonly default configuration in /usr/share etc., but that's never writable by users.
Sharing user-writable data will also give you a lot of syncing/locking headaches when multiple users on the system run the application simultaneously.

On Windows on OS X, user-writable configuration/data also goes to folders in the user directory, that'd be $HOME/Library/Application\ Support on Mac, and the registry plus C:\users\$Username\Application Data on Windows (the exact path depends on the Windows version. The environment variable %APPDATA% points to the location)).

To deviate from those standards, for a user/UI application (opposed to a system-wide daemon/service, where using /etc, /var is common practice) you should have *very* strong reasons, as they'll contradict what's expected on the systems, especially on Linux and also OS X. E.g., you'd need an installer on OS X, which is highly uncommon for user applications there. Users and especially Admins will hate you.

Comment: It's going to be a server application that's not supposed to be user dependent. Of course i'm going to stick to the standard for the client application, that's going to have an (optional) gui, per-user settings and all that fancy stuff, but for the server that's not relevant nor desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a ready Qt class to do it which following the same behaviour like each platform does.

But I think you could try to unify it for your own app on different platforms, for example, in $HOME/.yourapp directory or sth like it. For this way, QDesktopServices::storageLocation() could help you a bit.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation

Hope it helps.

Comment: QDesktopServices is not available if you only use QCoreApplication =(

Answer (score 0):

Why not store it in the same folder with the executable file:

```
QString fileName;

fileName = qApp->applicationDirPath();

fileName += "...what you want...";

QFile* file = new QFile(fileName);
```

Comment: That's not really possible... unless you want config file in /usr/bin and c:/program files/ ... and then you need to run it as root to be able to write to them and that's one of the requirements. always running as root is a bad thing... one mistake and a lot of customers are going to be very very angry when my app was used to gain access to their systems ;)